# Simple php soap request

Tags: php, soap

i making very simple test request. There is my document:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://localhost/webshop">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <web:TestRequest/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is my request:

```
$uri = '...';
$login = '...';
$pass = '...';
try{
 $client = new SoapClient($uri, Array('login' => $login, 'password' => $pass));
}catch(SoapFault $exception){
 $errors[] = 'Error: '.$exception;
}
//print_r($errors); //empty


if($client){
  $param = array();
  //var_dump($client);
  //var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
  $result = $client->__doRequest('TestRequest', $param);
  //$result = $client->TestRequest();
  var_dump($result); //return NULL
    echo "<br>";
  var_dump("REQUEST=", $client->__getLastRequest()); //return string(7) "REQUEST" NULL 
  var_dump("RESPONSE=", $client->__getLastResponse());//return string(8) "RESPONSE" NULL
}
```

Is it ok that it's return NULL? Or i made something wrong!?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the action parameter on your  **`__doRequest()`** . Refer [`here`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php)

Should be..

```
$result = $client->__doRequest('web:TestRequest', $param, $action, $version);
                                                          ----^--- ----^----
```

Comment: Sorry? but i'm really don't understand. What i need to add to action parameter.

Comment: Just pass it like `$result = $client->__doRequest('web:TestRequest',"","","",0);`